# Mastermind game in C(with words)

Tags: c

I am probably not going to get help here because my question is far from being specific (I don't even know what exactly wrong with it) but, according to my professor's tests, there is something wrong with it (wrong in terms of correctness - it doesn't provide correct number of direct and indirect matches) (I have no access to his tests). As far as I have been testing, it passes all of my tests. However, there are over a couple hundred million possible outcomes (I think) and I can't test them all because I don't know how to do automated testing...

Here is my code that performs the "logic" part of the game called mastermind, which is compares a string of randomly generated letter (8 max) with user input string (a guess). I wanted to see if anyone has encountered this game in the past and knows the logic of how it supposed to compare two strings and generate the correct number of exact and inexact guesses.

```
// userInput->position - a length of a string(max 8) 
// userInput->code - randomly generated code
// userInput->arr  - user input string
 void checkForExactMatch(Data* userInput) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < userInput->position; i++) {
       if (userInput->code[i] == userInput->arr[i]) {
          userInput->exactMatch++;
          userInput->arr[i] = 'a';
       }
       else
          checkForInExactMatch(userInput, i);
    }
 }

 void checkForInExactMatch(Data* userInput, int i) {
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < userInput->position; j++) {
       if (userInput->arr[j] == userInput->code[i]) {
          userInput->arr[j] = 'a';
          userInput->inExactMatch++;
          break;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in the code you show. Add comments on the lines where you want to tell us something, and add notes about it in the question body. Also please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: My guess is that your exact match needs to check all the characters before declaring an exact match, and then and only then if you do not have an exact match of all characters move to the inexact match (which will hinge on what your definition of an inexact match is), but I suspect if there is a substring match -- then you have an inexact match. Otherwise if less than some minimum number of characters are an inexact match -- you have neither. Great opportunity to learn from the duck -- [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You'll need a histogram of the letters in `userInput->code` and a separate histogram of the letters in `userInput->arr`. Exact matches are found by comparing elements of `code` with elements of `arr`. Inexact matches are found by comparing elements of the histograms.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin your were right on the spot. I revised my code according to your suggestions and it works perfectly fine now. If you turn your comment to an answer, I will tag it. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad it helped. I'll do a short write-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over your code there were a couple of observations to be made. First in your for `checkForExactMatch()` the call to `checkForInExactMatch` is inside your `for` loop. So on the first mismatch you call `checkForInExactMatch` and when you return from `checkForInExactMatch` -- you call it again on the next iteration unless your first mismatch just happens to be on the final character.

To address that issue, you should fully determine whether you have an exact match or not, completing the `for` loop before `checkForInExactMatch` is called.

In your `checkForInExactMatch`, you have to decide whether a single common-character or some minimum length substring constitutes an inexact match.

It sounds like you have things worked out, and good job for pushing through to a solution. Depending on how you approached it, keeping a simple flag in `checkForExactMatch()`such as `int matched = 1;` and then loop turning your test around

```
    for (i = 0; i < userInput->position; i++)
        if (userInput->code[i] != userInput->arr[i]) {
            matched = 0;
            break;
        }
```

Then it's just a simple test of

```
    if (matched) {
        userInput->exactMatch++;
        userInput->arr[i] = 'a';
    }
    else
        checkForInExactMatch(userInput, i);
```

So long as what you have done accomplishes something similar, you are fine. Let me know if you have further questions.